# Web Service Project endpoints are not accessible

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I have a webservice that can run on Tomcat v7, and can successfully expose the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/WS-LakeshoreMarketplace/HelloWorld`.  The details of this are described in my main class below:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloWorld
 */
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HelloWorld() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head><title>Hello, World!</title></head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello, Nadya, Nathan, and Vismark!!!</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("json");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("{\"message\": \"This is working!!!!!!\"}");
    }

}
```

Now, I have created a controller class to hold new endpoints that I'd like to expose, this class:

```java
package com.lakeshoremarketplace.controller;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/employee")
public class CustomerController {

    @GET
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    @Path("/example")
    public String getDummyEmployee() {
        return "success.";
    }
}
```

I've aso added the following class annotated with the `@ApplicationPath`, but it still does not work:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class DefaultController extends Application {
    
}
```

But when I try to access the `localhost:8080/employee/example` endpoint via a GET request, I get a 404 error.  This is happening when I try accessing through a browser, and through Postman. How can I successfully expose this endpoint on `localhost:8080/employee/example` as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your project doesn't contain any of the jars to support jersey.

Note: **That's a prior requirements for jersey to work.**

**Pull the new project from here :** https://github.com/anish-fullstack/WS-LakeshoreMarketplace

Now, I'm using tomcat 7 and JDK 8 (jdk will not be any issue). Change the JDK.

Updated project structure :

[image]

As you are using @ApplicationPath, then you don't to specify anything in the web.xml

Updated web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>WS-LakeshoreMarketplace</display-name>
</web-app>
```

**Success Tomcat 7 log :**

```
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/7.0.106
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Sep 16 2020 08:33:41 UTC
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 7.0.106.0
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.15.6
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_231-b11
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /Volumes/Local Disk/Software Development/Workspaces/Algorithms/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/anish/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.106
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Volumes/Local Disk/Software Development/Workspaces/Algorithms/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/anish/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.106
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Volumes/Local Disk/Software Development/Workspaces/Algorithms/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/anish/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.106/endorsed
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/anish/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 415 ms
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.106
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/Volumes/Local Disk/Software Development/Workspaces/Algorithms/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/WS-LakeshoreMarketplace/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 03, 2020 12:21:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 860 ms
```

Screenshot of accessing the URL :

[image]

That's all.

Comment: B, still not working -- I added a new class with the same annotation and base class as suggested (the question was updated with these details)

Comment: @VismarkJuarez Provide me the project on github. I will check.

Comment: B -- direct link: https://github.com/VismarkJuarez/WS-LakeshoreMarketplace

Comment: @VismarkJuarez I'm checking what's happening in the project.

Comment: @VismarkJuarez Your project doesn't contain jersey jars. Then, how it will run ?

Comment: @VismarkJuarez Fixed the issue. Updating my answer.